# Obj C: Navigation bar button appear after view appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, navigationbar

I have an info button as part of the custom overlay of my `UIImagePickerController`. When you click on it, I set the appearance of the navigation bar (which is hidden during the `UIImagePickerController` "presentation") and push a new view controller:

```
- (IBAction)infoButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    CameraHelpViewController *helpController = [[[CameraHelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraHelpViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
    [ipc pushViewController:helpController animated:NO];

}
```

CameraHelpViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Web view loading
    NSString *basePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    basePath = [basePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
    basePath = [basePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];      
    NSString *HTMLfile =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"camera_help" ofType:@"html"];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *stringFromPath = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:HTMLfile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] autorelease];     

    [webView loadHTMLString:stringFromPath baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//", basePath]]];
    webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];     
    webView.opaque = NO; // Prevents the white flash from occurring     
    [_activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

//UPDATE:
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

UPDATE since using code from [@ryancrunchi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4392254/ryancrunchi), the navigation bar button does not move into view. Instead, the navigation bar moves up a few seconds after the view loads.

[image]

I would like to have the navigation bar fully set before the new view appears. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

With these lines :

`[ipc setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
[ipc pushViewController:helpController animated:NO];`

you are animating the navigation bar but you present your `helpController` without animation. So the `helpController` appears before navigation bar which itself is playing animation (delayed showing).
If you don't want animation at all, put `[ipc setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];` in your `CameraHelpViewController` :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [ipc setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    // or
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

and hide the bar when view disappears :

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [ipc setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    // or
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: If I don't want animation, I put `YES` ? I implemented your `viewWillAppear`, but the button still sets after view appears. (Also `CameraHelpViewController` doesn't have access to `ipc`)

Comment: ofc, `animated:NO` for no animation, edited. If you don't have access to `ipc` use `self.navigationController`

Comment: button is still appearing after the view appears

Comment: Did you remove `[ipc setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];` from `infoButtonPressed:` ?

Comment: I removed that line. Instead of the nav bar button moving into frame, it animates the whole navigation bar once the view loads. I updated my question with a gif

Comment: try replacing `animated:animated` with `animated:NO`